# Out of USPTO and GCC which one should be filed first?

Tags: uspto, priority

I want to protect my invention in gulf and US both. Now shall I first file in Gulf (GCC) and then move to USPTO or the V.V ?

Answer (score 1):

If you **reside** in Gulf Cooperation Council (GCC) country, e.g., Saudi Arabia, then you would typically file in your home jurisdiction first (e.g., via The Patent Office of the Cooperation Council for the Arab States of the Gulf) and then use the Paris Convention or the Patent Cooperation Treaty (PCT) to pursue patent protection abroad while maintaining the benefit of priority to your home country filing.

However, if you **reside** in the US, then you would typically perform your first filing with the USPTO.